# Failed to find module vfio_pci

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualization, amd-graphics, 19.10

I am attempting to pass through a GPU to a virtual machine following [this](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-17-04-vfio-pcie-passthrough-kernel-update-4-14-rc1) guide, which means that I must replace the drivers used with `vfio_pci`. I have followed this guide up to the step just before the installation/configuration of QEMU.

Instead of showing that the current kernal driver of GPU the is vfio_pci, it shows that the default amdgpu one is used. [result from `lspci -k`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2F0.png):

When booting the following message appears:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details
```

[result of `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSxDW.png)

How would I resolve this issue and have the GPU use the correct driver?

**NOTE: Ubuntu 19.10 is being used**

**EDIT 1:** [`output from apt-cache policy linux-image-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHTui.png), linux extras not found

**EDIT 2:** `modprobe vfio_pci` succeeds so it appears that the vfio_pci driver is installed/valid

**EDIT 3:** result of `dpkg -S vfio-pci.ko`

```
linux-modules-5.3.0-29-generic: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/vfio/pci/vfio-pci.ko
linux-modules-5.3.0-18-generic: /lib/modules/5.3.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/vfio/pci/vfio-pci.ko
```

Comment: Do you have installed all kernel modules? Please add output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert After messing around with my system (trying to make sure that everything was up to date, ect.), I could not get vfio_pci to appear on boot.

Comment: To be completely sure please add output of `dpkg -S vfio-pci.ko` to the question in text form (not screenshot).

Comment: @N0rbert Checked the result from `dpkg -S vfio-pci.ko` and it defiantly appears that the driver is active and installed (at least when the system is fully booted).

Comment: @N0rbert It seems like that error is caused by passing the device ids to `vfio_pci` like `vfio_pci ids=1002:731f,1002:ab38`, but if I leave the ids out (keeping them on the options line) they are not bound to the devices (they still use amdgpu).

Comment: All this magic depend on CPU and motherboard capabilities. See for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF as a good reference.

Comment: @N0rbert I looked at the page and the process is quite similar to the one I was using (at least in the *Isolating the GPU* section, where I have issues as well as the first step on setting up IOMMU). I have confirmed that my CPU (AMD R9 3900x) supports virtualization extensions and have them enabled along with IOMMU (and passed the sanity checks there). To make sure I went through the steps on that page, but was met with the exact same result as before. When searching for other sites/methods they all seems to a similar thing as well (quickly tried a few of them for good measure as well).